# system command in C forced to run in serial on OSX?

Tags: c, macos, openmp

I am using Mac OSX 10.8.4 and programming in C. I trying to use openmp and I am compiling with gcc-mp-4.7. I am working in bash. Currently I have an executable (I will call executable1 in the program) which I am trying to run in parallel by using a system call inside of an openmp parallel for loop. The example code is as follows:

## my_omp.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <omp.h>

void main() {
    int n = 100;

    double var1         = 65.4;
    char place[100]     = "/under/a/rock";
    double var2         = 4.5e4;
    double var3;

    char program[200];

    int i;
#pragma omp parallel for private(program,var3)
    for (i=0; i<=n; i++) {
        var3 = var1*pow(var2,i);
        sprintf(program,"./executable1 %.15e %s %.15e %d", var1, place, var2, var3, i);
        printf("%s \n", program);
        system(program);
    }

}
```

I compile the program using `gcc-mp-4.7 -fopenmp my_omp.c`, then run the newly compiled executable, (differently named than exectuable1).

What seems to happen is that 8 (which I believe is the number of "cpus" openmp thinks I have) of the print statements will appear in the stdout (terminal) and then it will run only a single call of the executable1, then when it finishes it prints out another of the printf program lines, then runs another executable1 until it finishes the for loop (I know this because executable1 is extremely verbose, and it would be obvious is two where running as numbers printed to stdout would be out of synch and appearing in at multiples).

So it seems maybe that the printf is running in parallel, but for some reason the system() command is not? Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks for any help you can offer.

## UPDATE:

I have gotten this exact code to run properly on a lunix distribution with a different compiler, I will look into finding a better compiler to use in Mac OSX and see if that works.

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is. Is the output garbled? If so, can you post a sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `system(3)` library call in OS X is implemented using a global mutex lock - see the [system.c](http://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-825.26/stdlib/FreeBSD/system.c) file in the source code of OS X's C library:

```
#if __DARWIN_UNIX03
    pthread_mutex_lock(&__systemfn_mutex);
#endif /* __DARWIN_UNIX03 */
...
#if __DARWIN_UNIX03
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&__systemfn_mutex);
#endif /* __DARWIN_UNIX03 */
```

Therefore when one thread calls into `system(3)`, all other threads have to wait for the first call to finish, resulting in serialised execution.

Comment: I'm not a super computer wiz, is there an easy work around for this? Or am I pretty much screwed working in OSX? Thanks a bunch for confirming my suspicions.

Comment: No, that's part of the implementation. Of course, you can compile your own version of `system()` and take out the code for the mutex, but then you'll have to add directives for conditional compilation to your code in order to keep it portable.